# How to use a "if" condition properly in batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, goto

Sorry for my bad english expression ... i'm not native.
I have searched for an answer for a while ... maybe i'm not doing this right but it seems that my (simple) code is not working for a reason.
As soon as I open the batch programm it shuts without me having the time to read the error message :(
could some one please correct this one ??
I am grateful for any kind of help !

```
    @echo off
    color 0a
    mode 1000
    title THE OFFSWITCH
    :start
    cls
    if %time%== "12:00:00.00" goto :time
    echo.
    echo                                         IT IS NOT TIME YET : %time%
    goto start
    :time
    echo hello 
    pause>nul
```

Comment: First need to %time% in quotes for proper comparison.. Second you need brackets if you you want a new line after if cndition. I m writing from my phone and cant give you more precise answer at the moment

Comment: Shouldn't `goto :time` be `goto time` in your IF

Comment: Thanks for the help (npocmaka) IT WORKED !!
I will share with you the result :

    `@echo off
    color 0a
    mode 1000
    title THE OFFSWITCH
    :start
    cls
    set time=%time%
    if "%time%"== "12:25:00.00" goto time

    echo                                         IT IS NOT TIME YET : %time%

    goto start

    :time
    echo hello 
    pause>nul`

Answer (score 0):

It is pure luck, if your code works. In the most cases, it will just miss the time, because the loop is not fast enough to get the correct centisecond.

Instead of

```
if %time%== "12:00:00.00" goto :time
```

you should use

```
if "%time%" geq "12:00:00.00" goto :time
```

(if time is "greater or equal" than...)

Also you should consider to put a delay into the loop, because it eats all of the CPU-Time, it can get, and thus slows down your system. For example `timeout /t 1>nul` waits for one second.